# Can I use varbinary type to store image in SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to store an image in my SQL Server database, what datatype should I use?

In the below `code aspx.cs`, I am trying to read all the bytes from the request inputstream and store it in the database, but the `byte[]` array is not updated properly in table. Am I missing something?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

        byte[] Contents = new byte[Request.InputStream.Length];

        Request.InputStream.Read(Contents, 0, (int)Request.InputStream.Length);

        con.Open();

        try
        {
            string query = "update tblImageUpload set " + IMAGE_ID + " = @imageBytes where Image_ID='" + CID + "'";

            int i = 0;

            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@imageBytes", SqlDbType.VarBinary, Contents.Length).Value = Contents;

                 i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            Response.Write("Upload Query = " + query);
            Response.Write("Upload Code = " + i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Write("Upload Code=" + ex);
        }
```

Comment: `you can use VarBinary(Max)` sorry typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `VARBINARY` yes. You're probably best off going with `VARBINARY(MAX)` to store them.

You can use it like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@imageBytes", SqlDbType.VarBinaryMax);
cmd.Parameters["@imageBytes"].Value = Contents;
```

Comment: i was trying to use CAST AS operator but it dint work,but parameterized sql query works great, is there any any restriction on the size of the image to upload , i have about 10 image column in a table

Comment: @deepak Well that'd be restricted to the max size `VARBINARY` can hold, which is 2^31-1 bytes. Unless you're planning on storing 2 gigapixel and above images, I think you'll be fine :)

Comment: `VarBinaryMax` is not a valid `enum` option.