# how to insert image using command.Parameters

Tags: c#-4.0

When I insert image to db it is blank.

This is my code:

```
            string sql = "INSERT INTO tblProfile(EmployeeID,FirstName, MiddleName,LastName,Gender,Age,Email, DateofBirth,RFID,PlaceofBirth,MaritalStatus,SSS,TIN,PhilHealth, Mobile,City, HomeAddress, Nationality, Religion,ContactPerson,ContactNumber,Image)" +
                "VALUES(@ID,@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@Gender,@Age,@Email,@DateofBirth,@RFID,@PlaceofBirth,@MaritalStatus,@SSS,@TIN,@PhilHealth, @Mobile,@City,@HomeAddress, @Nationality, @Religion,@ContactPerson,@ContactNumber,@IMG)";
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            command.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(txtContactNumber_New.Text);                                               
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG", img));
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Insert-Update-Image-To-SQL-Server.html
Please provide some more code. What is your img object type

Comment: I'm using varbinary for the image data type.the rest is inserting only the image is blank.

Comment: Do you use memorystream ? Also I need datatype of Img in .net rather than in DB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645812/can-i-use-varbinary-type-to-store-image-in-sql-server-database

Comment: I'm not using memorystream. datatype SqlDbType.varbinary

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get from link in comment you have to do following thing.

```
byte[] img = // Read you image as byte array.
var _SqlParameter  = new SqlParameter("@Img", SqlDbType.Image);
_SqlParameter.Value = img;
// In above line img should be by array.
```

More complete example you will find here.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)